# PHP parsing multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

HI I need to parse a multi dimensional array

```
$myArray = array(
    array('id' => 6),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'children' => array(
            'id' => 5,
            'children' => array(
                'id' => 7,
                'children' => array(
                    array('id' => 4), 
                    array('id' => 1)
                ),
                array('id' => 8)
            )
        )
    ),
    array('id' => 2)
);
```

Here's the output I need as a string or array...

```
6
3
3,5
3,5,7
3,5,7,4
3,5,7,1
3,5,8
2
```

Comment: Implode and a simple loop should do.

Comment: this is not a site to ask such give me the code questions, first you have to try.

Comment: Are you sure, your data structure is correct this way? I just reformatted the array you gave us and as you see, `children` sometimes onsists of one, sometimes of two objects.

Comment: Additionally you can see, that `array('id' => 8)` does have none (a numeric) key...

Comment: Welcome to our community. We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a recursive loop:

```
$children = array();

function getChilren($myArray, $children){

     foreach($myArray as $value){
          if(is_array($value)){
              $cLen = count($children);
              $children[] = $children[$cLen-1];
              getChildren($value, $children[$cLen]);
          }
          else {
              $children[] = $value;
          }
      }
 }
```

This may be flawed, and need more to work, but I think its at least a start.